# WP_User_Query with 2 sets of conditions 'AND'

Tags: wp-user-query

I would like to write some arguments for my query and both need to be true.  I am having trouble with the Syntax.

'meta_key' => $campaign_type,

'meta_value' => $Campaign_ID,

**AND**

'meta_key' => 'organisation',

'meta_value' => $userOrg,

Below is my query code:

```
$args = array (
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'meta_key' => $campaign_type, 
        'meta_value' => $Campaign_ID,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'meta_key' => 'organisation',
        'meta_value' => $userOrg,
        'compare' => '='
    )
));
```

Thank you.

Comment: It looks OK, so query itself is not the problem. Are you sure that these conditions are correct?

Comment: The only thing that I'm not sure about is the 'meta_key' vs 'key'.  I am using ACF for 'organisation' and UserMeta for '$campaign_type'.

Comment: the query you use won't work because meta_query only accept post meta

Comment: What should I be using to query the User Meta?

Comment: @TungDu of course you can use `meta_query` with `WP_User_Query` - just take a look at Codex ;)

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Ah, sorry about that. A mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an example here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Problem with your query is that you use wrong keys. It should be:

```
$args = array (
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => $campaign_type, 
            'value' => $Campaign_ID,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'organisation',
            'value' => $userOrg,
            'compare' => '='
        )
));
```

Longer versions (`meta_key`, `meta_value`, `meta_compare`) are used, when you don't use `meta_query` but put them directly in the query.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  Also thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'last_name',
    's'  =>  $_GET['search_text'],
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'name_organization', //ACF custom field
            'value'   => $text,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name', //User name
            'value'   => $text,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    )
);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?